# How to Instantiate a class with the class type, using constructor of extended class with method 'getDeclaredConstructor', in Android Studio

Tags: java, class, android-studio, enums

```
public class MainMenu extends GameMenu{

Table table;

Skin skin;

public MainMenu(){super();};

protected void loadWidgets(){

    skin.add("playButton", com.mygdx.game.LIBGDXwrapper.gameGUI.widgets.MainMenuWidgets.loadPlayButton(table));
    table.row();
    skin.add("hightScoreButton", com.mygdx.game.LIBGDXwrapper.gameGUI.widgets.MainMenuWidgets.loadHighScoreButton(table));
    //table.row();
}

protected void loadInputlisteners(){
    skin.get("playButton", Button.class);

}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Menu";
}
}





public abstract class GameMenu extends Stage{

private Settings gameSettings;

//public GameMenu(Settings gameSettings){
 //   this.gameSettings = gameSettings;
//}

public GameMenu(){};

protected abstract void loadWidgets();

protected abstract void loadInputlisteners();

}



private static enum GameMenus {MainMenu(MainMenu.class);
    private final Class<? extends GameMenu> menuType;

    GameMenus(Class<? extends GameMenu> menuType){
        this.menuType = menuType;
    }

    public Class<? extends GameMenu> createInstance(Settings gameSettings){
        GameMenu gui = menuType.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }
};
```

I have been trying to make this work for hours now, is it possible to get an instance of a derived class from 'GameMenu' with the class type 'Class< ? extends GameMenu>'? Note that all derived classes of 'GameMenu' have a constructor that with one argument 'Settings'.

I'm getting NoSuchMethodExpection from the method 'getDeclaredConstructor'.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Possible XY Problem type question

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: It's possible. Here's an example: http://ideone.com/WcwHMC. It sounds like you have some other issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I'm trying to instantiate a class with the a given class type, for now only MainMenu by passing as argument GameMenus.MainMenu.

I could just make a swicth(gameMenus) and instantiate in each case the right class but that would be sloppy.

Comment: Here's an example of an MCVE which could cause the exception you are getting: http://ideone.com/2G6e1B. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to update the question with enough code for us to reproduce the error. The full exception stack trace would be helpful too.

Comment: @Radiodef The getDeclaredConstructor keeps saying NoSuhMethod despite the method existing on the super abstract class and on all extended classes, I've tried to make a constructer with no arguments on all classes but I keep getting the NoSuhMethod expection.

Comment: Well, we can't help without the question being updated with the information I suggested. (MCVE/stack trace)

Comment: @Radiodef working on it

Comment: I thought of another reason this could happen: http://ideone.com/fk2NtJ.

Comment: There is no stack trace just the error: 
Error:(26, 44) error: unreported exception NoSuchMethodException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: AAH just found out the problem, android studio requires me to add a try catch around it.

Comment: @Radiodef Well, thanks at least I learned something new with your last ideone program.

Answer (score 0):

So you said:

> Note that all derived classes of 'GameMenu' have a constructor that with one argument 'Settings'.

But you use:

```
menuType.getDeclaredConstructor()
```

If you take a look at [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), you will see that `getDeclaredConstructor()` returns the "no args" constructor if any.
You probably want to specify the constructor argument type:

```
menuType.getDeclaredConstructor(Settings.class)
```

Comment: The main problem was that I am required to add a try catch around the getDeclaredConstructer() method, android studio demanded it. Thank you anyway.